# Não estou conseguindo deixar o meu arquivo final expandido com o gulp-sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp

olá,não estou conseguindo deixar meu arquivo final .css expandido,já tentei colocar
no outputStyle a palavra expanded mas o arquivo continua compressado ai vai o código onde está todo o código sass.

```
//Adiciona os modulos instalados

const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

//Função para compilar o SASS e adicionar os prefixos

function compilaSass(){
  return gulp.src('css/scss/*.scss').pipe(sass(
    {outputStyle: 'expanded'}
    )).pipe(autoprefixer({
    browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
    cascade: false
    })).pipe(gulp.dest('css/')).pipe(browserSync.stream());

}

//Tarefa de gulp para a função de SASS

gulp.task('sass',compilaSass);

//Função para iniciar o servidor do browser

function browser(){
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    }
  })
}

//tarefa do browser-sync

gulp.task('browser',browser);

//Função de watch do GULP 

function watch(){
  gulp.watch('css/scss/*.scss',compilaSass);
  gulp.watch(['*.html','*.js']).on('change',browserSync.reload);

}

//inicia a tarefa de watch 

gulp.task('watch',watch);

//Tarefa padrão do GULP,que inicia o watch e o browser-sync

gulp.task('default',gulp.parallel('watch','browser'));
//Para finalizar a tarefa use o crt + C
```

Comment: Vc não tem nenhuma outra extensão tipo o  Beautifier ou Pretyfy que já minifica o CSS quando ele é salvo?

Comment: não só esses ai